# How to format adaptive cards like the old version of webchat

Tags: html, css, botframework, adaptive-cards, web-chat

The new version of the standard webchat channel ("gemini") stripped out all of the formatting. I was able to replicate most of the old interface via tweaks in the botframework-webchat implementation, but I cannot get the adaptive card formatting to match. With the general formatting I was able to get it close, and the adaptiveCardHostConfig tweaks shown [here on Github](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/2772) got a bit closer, but I still can't figure out how to replicate it. Specifically, the chat bubble (which is gray in my implementation) no longer appears behind the adaptive card. This is especially noticeable for carousels, where it used to be one "bubble" with multiple cards and is now discrete cards. Furthermore, the buttons are no longer interactive (blue border used to appear on mouseover), and the bublle "nub" is absent. Please see below for examples. Note that I DO know how to make the background for the card itself gray to match the bubbles, but that is not the look that I want or that displayed previously.

In summary, I'm asking

1. How can I format the gray background like was present in the previous version.
2. How can I add the bubble nub to the card (or perhaps more accurately, make the card appear inside a bubble).
3. How can I make the buttons on the adaptive card interactive

Single Card (new on left, old on right)
[image: single-card]

Carousel (new on left, old on right)
[image]

And here is the website code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Support Bot</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>

        <style>
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: 0;
        }

        #chatbotTitle {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            height: 40px;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #0067CC;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-family: Calibri, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

        #webchat {
            height: calc(100% - 40px);
            width: 100%;
        }

        .btn {
            display: flex;
            background-color: white;
            border: 1px solid #767676;
            color: #0067CC;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 15px;
        }

        .btn:hover {
            border-color: #444444;
        }

        .btn:active {
            background-color: #CCCCCC;
        }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chatbotTitle"><h3 style="padding-left:10px;">Support Bot</h3><button class="btn" id="transcriptButton">Email Transcript</button></div>
        <div id="webchat" role="main"></div>
        <script>
            let interval;

            var PageTitleNotification = {
                Vars:{
                    OriginalTitle: document.title,
                    Interval: null
                },    
                On: function(notification, intervalSpeed){
                    var _this = this;
                    _this.Vars.Interval = setInterval(function(){
                        document.title = (_this.Vars.OriginalTitle == document.title)
                                 ? notification
                                 : _this.Vars.OriginalTitle;
                    }, (intervalSpeed) ? intervalSpeed : 1000);
                },
                Off: function(){
                    clearInterval(this.Vars.Interval);
                    document.title = this.Vars.OriginalTitle;   
                }
            }

            // We are using a customized store to add hooks to connect event
            const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {

                if (action.type === 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_MESSAGE') {
                    // Message sent by the user
                    PageTitleNotification.Off();
                    clearTimeout(interval);
                } else if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY' && action.payload.activity.name !== "inactive") {
                    // Message sent by the bot
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    interval = setTimeout(() => {
                        // Change title to flash the page
                        PageTitleNotification.On('Are you still there?');

                        // Notify bot the user has been inactive
                        dispatch({
                            type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
                            payload: {
                                name: 'inactive',
                                value: ''
                            }
                        });
                    }, 300000)
                }

                return next(action);
            });

            const adaptiveCardHostConfig = {
                "spacing": {
                    "small": 3,
                    "default": 8,
                    "medium": 20,
                    "large": 30,
                    "extraLarge": 40,
                    "padding": 10
                },
                "separator": {
                    "lineThickness": 1,
                    "lineColor": "#EEEEEE"
                },
                "supportsInteractivity": true,
                "fontTypes": {
                    "default": {
                    "fontFamily": "Calibri, sans-serif",
                    "fontSizes": {
                        "small": 12,
                        "default": 14,
                        "medium": 17,
                        "large": 21,
                        "extraLarge": 26
                    },
                    "fontWeights": {
                        "lighter": 200,
                        "default": 400,
                        "bolder": 600
                    }
                    },
                    "monospace": {
                    "fontFamily": "'Courier New', Courier, monospace",
                    "fontSizes": {
                        "small": 12,
                        "default": 14,
                        "medium": 17,
                        "large": 21,
                        "extraLarge": 26
                    },
                    "fontWeights": {
                        "lighter": 200,
                        "default": 400,
                        "bolder": 600
                    }
                    }
                },
                "containerStyles": {
                    "default": {
                    "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
                    "foregroundColors": {
                        "default": {
                        "default": "#000000",
                        "subtle": "#767676"
                        },
                        "accent": {
                        "default": "#0063B1",
                        "subtle": "#0063B1"
                        },
                        "attention": {
                        "default": "#FF0000",
                        "subtle": "#DDFF0000"
                        },
                        "good": {
                        "default": "#54a254",
                        "subtle": "#DD54a254"
                        },
                        "warning": {
                        "default": "#c3ab23",
                        "subtle": "#DDc3ab23"
                        }
                    }
                    },
                    "emphasis": {
                    "backgroundColor": "#F0F0F0",
                    "foregroundColors": {
                        "default": {
                        "default": "#000000",
                        "subtle": "#767676"
                        },
                        "accent": {
                        "default": "#2E89FC",
                        "subtle": "#882E89FC"
                        },
                        "attention": {
                        "default": "#FF0000",
                        "subtle": "#DDFF0000"
                        },
                        "good": {
                        "default": "#54a254",
                        "subtle": "#DD54a254"
                        },
                        "warning": {
                        "default": "#c3ab23",
                        "subtle": "#DDc3ab23"
                        }
                    }
                    },
                    "accent": {
                    "backgroundColor": "#C7DEF9",
                    "foregroundColors": {
                        "default": {
                        "default": "#333333",
                        "subtle": "#EE333333"
                        },
                        "dark": {
                        "default": "#000000",
                        "subtle": "#66000000"
                        },
                        "light": {
                        "default": "#FFFFFF",
                        "subtle": "#33000000"
                        },
                        "accent": {
                        "default": "#2E89FC",
                        "subtle": "#882E89FC"
                        },
                        "attention": {
                        "default": "#cc3300",
                        "subtle": "#DDcc3300"
                        },
                        "good": {
                        "default": "#54a254",
                        "subtle": "#DD54a254"
                        },
                        "warning": {
                        "default": "#e69500",
                        "subtle": "#DDe69500"
                        }
                    }
                    },
                    "good": {
                    "backgroundColor": "#CCFFCC",
                    "foregroundColors": {
                        "default": {
                        "default": "#333333",
                        "subtle": "#EE333333"
                        },
                        "dark": {
                        "default": "#000000",
                        "subtle": "#66000000"
                        },
                        "light": {
                        "default": "#FFFFFF",
                        "subtle": "#33000000"
                        },
                        "accent": {
                        "default": "#2E89FC",
                        "subtle": "#882E89FC"
                        },
                        "attention": {
                        "default": "#cc3300",
                        "subtle": "#DDcc3300"
                        },
                        "good": {
                        "default": "#54a254",
                        "subtle": "#DD54a254"
                        },
                        "warning": {
                        "default": "#e69500",
                        "subtle": "#DDe69500"
                        }
                    }
                    },
                    "attention": {
                    "backgroundColor": "#FFC5B2",
                    "foregroundColors": {
                        "default": {
                        "default": "#333333",
                        "subtle": "#EE333333"
                        },
                        "dark": {
                        "default": "#000000",
                        "subtle": "#66000000"
                        },
                        "light": {
                        "default": "#FFFFFF",
                        "subtle": "#33000000"
                        },
                        "accent": {
                        "default": "#2E89FC",
                        "subtle": "#882E89FC"
                        },
                        "attention": {
                        "default": "#cc3300",
                        "subtle": "#DDcc3300"
                        },
                        "good": {
                        "default": "#54a254",
                        "subtle": "#DD54a254"
                        },
                        "warning": {
                        "default": "#e69500",
                        "subtle": "#DDe69500"
                        }
                    }
                    },
                    "warning": {
                    "backgroundColor": "#FFE2B2",
                    "foregroundColors": {
                        "default": {
                        "default": "#333333",
                        "subtle": "#EE333333"
                        },
                        "dark": {
                        "default": "#000000",
                        "subtle": "#66000000"
                        },
                        "light": {
                        "default": "#FFFFFF",
                        "subtle": "#33000000"
                        },
                        "accent": {
                        "default": "#2E89FC",
                        "subtle": "#882E89FC"
                        },
                        "attention": {
                        "default": "#cc3300",
                        "subtle": "#DDcc3300"
                        },
                        "good": {
                        "default": "#54a254",
                        "subtle": "#DD54a254"
                        },
                        "warning": {
                        "default": "#e69500",
                        "subtle": "#DDe69500"
                        }
                    }
                    }
                },
                "imageSizes": {
                    "small": 40,
                    "medium": 80,
                    "large": 160
                },
                "actions": {
                    "maxActions": 100,
                    "spacing": "default",
                    "buttonSpacing": 8,
                    "showCard": {
                    "actionMode": "inline",
                    "inlineTopMargin": 8
                    },
                    "actionsOrientation": "vertical",
                    "actionAlignment": "stretch"
                },
                "adaptiveCard": {
                    "allowCustomStyle": false
                },
                "imageSet": {
                    "imageSize": "medium",
                    "maxImageHeight": 100
                },
                "factSet": {
                    "title": {
                    "color": "default",
                    "size": "default",
                    "isSubtle": false,
                    "weight": "bolder",
                    "wrap": true,
                    "maxWidth": 150
                    },
                    "value": {
                    "color": "default",
                    "size": "default",
                    "isSubtle": false,
                    "weight": "default",
                    "wrap": true
                    },
                    "spacing": 8
                }
            };

            window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
                {
                    adaptiveCardHostConfig,
                    directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
                        token: 'MYTOKENHERE'
                    }),
                    store: store,
                    userID: 'userID',
                    username: 'userName',
                    locale: 'en-US',
                    styleOptions: {
                        botAvatarInitials: 'BOT',
                        userAvatarInitials: 'USR',
                        accent: '#0067CC',
                        backgroundColor: 'White',
                        cardEmphasisBackgroundColor: '#F0F0F0',
                        paddingRegular: 10,
                        paddingWide: 10 * 2,
                        messageActivityWordBreak: 'break-word',
                        fontSizeSmall: '80%',
                        avatarSize: 40,
                        botAvatarBackgroundColor: '#0067CC',
                        botAvatarImage: '',
                        botAvatarInitials: '',
                        userAvatarBackgroundColor: '#ECEFF1',
                        userAvatarImage: '',
                        userAvatarInitials: '',
                        bubbleBackground: '#ECEFF1',
                        bubbleBorderColor: '#E6E6E6',
                        bubbleBorderRadius: 8,
                        bubbleBorderStyle: 'solid',
                        bubbleBorderWidth: 1,
                        bubbleFromUserBackground: '#0067CC',
                        bubbleFromUserBorderColor: '#E6E6E6',
                        bubbleFromUserBorderRadius: 8,
                        bubbleFromUserBorderStyle: 'solid',
                        bubbleFromUserBorderWidth: 1,
                        bubbleFromUserNubOffset: 'bottom',
                        bubbleFromUserNubSize: 10,
                        bubbleFromUserTextColor: 'White',
                        bubbleImageHeight: 240,
                        bubbleMaxWidth: 480,
                        bubbleMinHeight: 30,
                        bubbleMinWidth: 250,
                        bubbleNubOffset: 'bottom',
                        bubbleNubSize: 10,
                        bubbleTextColor: 'Black',
                        markdownRespectCRLF: true,
                        richCardWrapTitle: false,
                        rootHeight: '100%',
                        rootWidth: '100%',
                        hideScrollToEndButton: false,
                        hideSendBox: false,
                        hideUploadButton: true,
                        microphoneButtonColorOnDictate: '#F33',
                        sendBoxBackground: 'White',
                        sendBoxButtonColor: '#767676',
                        sendBoxButtonColorOnDisabled: '#CCC',
                        sendBoxButtonColorOnFocus: '#0067CC',
                        sendBoxButtonColorOnHover: '#0067CC',
                        sendBoxDisabledTextColor: '#767676', // defaults to subtle
                        sendBoxHeight: 40,
                        sendBoxMaxHeight: 200,
                        sendBoxTextColor: 'Black',
                        sendBoxBorderBottom: 'solid 5px #DBDEE1',
                        sendBoxBorderLeft: 'solid 5px #DBDEE1',
                        sendBoxBorderRight: 'solid 5px #DBDEE1',
                        sendBoxBorderTop: 'solid 5px #DBDEE1',
                        sendBoxPlaceholderColor: undefined, // defaults to subtle
                        sendBoxTextWrap: false,
                        showSpokenText: false,
                        suggestedActionBackground: 'White',
                        suggestedActionBorder: undefined,
                        suggestedActionBorderColor: '#CCCCCC',
                        suggestedActionBorderRadius: 0,
                        suggestedActionBorderStyle: 'solid',
                        suggestedActionBorderWidth: 1,
                        suggestedActionDisabledBackground: '#F9F9F9',
                        suggestedActionDisabledBorder: null,
                        suggestedActionDisabledBorderColor: '#E6E6E6',
                        suggestedActionDisabledBorderStyle: 'solid',
                        suggestedActionDisabledBorderWidth: 1,
                        suggestedActionDisabledTextColor: '#767676',
                        suggestedActionHeight: 30,
                        suggestedActionImageHeight: 20,
                        suggestedActionLayout: 'carousel',
                        suggestedActionTextColor: null,
                        groupTimestamp: false,
                        sendTimeout: 20000,
                        sendTimeoutForAttachments: 120000,
                        timestampColor: '#767676',
                        timestampFormat: 'relative',
                        transcriptOverlayButtonBackground: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .6)',
                        transcriptOverlayButtonBackgroundOnFocus: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .8)',
                        transcriptOverlayButtonBackgroundOnHover: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .8)',
                        transcriptOverlayButtonColor: 'White',
                        transcriptOverlayButtonColorOnFocus: 'White',
                        transcriptOverlayButtonColorOnHover: 'White',
                        typingAnimationBackgroundImage: null,
                        typingAnimationDuration: 5000,
                        typingAnimationHeight: 20,
                        typingAnimationWidth: 64,
                        subtle: '#767676'
                    }
                },
                document.getElementById('webchat')
            );

            document.querySelector('#transcriptButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
                store.dispatch({
                    type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_MESSAGE',
                    payload: { text: 'Email me a transcript' }
                });
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @tdurnford separate question added

Comment: I presume you must have gotten the term "Gemini" from [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56286657/how-to-fix-issues-related-to-directlinechannel-prompt-choice-options-not-display) of TJ's [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648170/web-chat-did-not-display-the-result) because that's not a commonly-understood term. Can you confirm that when you say Gemini you're referring to Web Chat v4 and when you say old you're referring to Web Chat v3 aka Bot Chat? Also, when you talk about making buttons "interactive" are you talking about on-hover effects? (Sorry my team forgot your post)

Comment: @KyleDelaney Sorry, gemini is in the redirect URL so I was using that to differentiate. I'm not exactly sure on the version, but it is quite possible that it is v3 vs. v4. And yes, referring to on-hover effects. I've tried using a custom adaptiveCardHostConfig object (which can effect some changes), but I cannot replicate the look or function of the old cards. I would be quite happy if I could just get the cards to render exactly like they did in the old version.

Comment: Do you mean the embed URL? It looks like you're using the CDN in your HTML and not using embedded Web Chat so there's no reference to the term Gemini there. Is that not the case?

Comment: @KyleDelaney You are correct. The screenshots on the left are via the CDN/Directline. But without my formatting tweaks in styleOptions and adaptiveCardHost it is identical to the embed URL (which I have been calling OOTB webchat). On the right is the old version of the embed URL.

Comment: To be clear, you are seeing the bubble nub on regular messages and just not on attachments, right? You might be interested in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/2667

Comment: @KyleDelaney Correct. There are other things I'm trying to replicate from the old version (text size and style on button, nesting the attachment inside a speech bubble, onHover effects on the buttons).

Comment: I’ll need some time to check it out and will get back to you

Comment: Have you had a chance to check it out yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Web Chat](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) and [Adaptive Cards](https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards) are both open source, so it's a good idea to download their source code if you want to figure out how they work. In the Web Chat repo you can switch to the v3 branch to see how v3 works. Web Chat uses the Adaptive Cards JavaScript SDK, and the code that handles parsing and rendering is in [card-elements.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/blob/master/source/nodejs/adaptivecards/src/card-elements.ts).

In [botchat.css](https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css), you can see the styles that create the background you want here:

> ```
> .wc-message-content {
>   border-radius: 2px;
>   box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
>   padding: 8px;
>   word-break: break-word; }
>
> .wc-message-from-bot .wc-message-content {
>   background-color: #eceff1;
>   color: #000000; }
> ```

Those classes aren't used in Web Chat v4, but you can apply it to your attachments and carousels like this:

```
div.attachment.bubble,
div.content > ul.webchat__carousel__item_indented {
    background-color: #eceff1;
    color: #000000;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding: 8px;
}
```

I'm being pretty specific with the selector because there's another style that will try to set the padding to 0. You can just use the `!important` keyword if you want.

You've already seen that Web Chat doesn't allow bubble nubs on attachments in v4. The line responsible for this is [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/packages/component/src/Activity/StackedLayout.js#L164):

> ```
> <Bubble className="attachment bubble" fromUser={fromUser} key={index} nub={false}>
> ```

You can modify the way activities are rendered using activity middleware according to [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/05.custom-components/c.user-highlighting). In your case you'll want to render an SVG element alongside the activity.

To add hover styles to your buttons, you can again have a look at [botchat.css](https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css):

> ```
> .wc-card button:hover {
>   background-color: transparent;
>   border-color: #0078d7;
>   color: #0078d7; }
> ```

You can use all three of those declarations or just `border-color`:

```
.ac-adaptiveCard button:hover {
    border-color: #0078d7;
}
```

Comment: This got me most of the way there. The biggest remaining gap is carousels, but I think I may not be able to replicate that exactly due to the elements rendering in individual speech bubbles instead of multiple elements inside one speech bubble. Style changes appear to affect all cards, not just the carousel output.

Comment: The reason I applied the style to both `div.attachment.bubble` and `div.content > ul.webchat__carousel__item_indented` is so that it would work for carousels. Are you saying you're observing undesired behavior? Can you edit a screenshot into your question and inspect the HTML of your page to see why that might be happening?

Comment: The screenshot is already in the question. The main difference is that the contents of the card are just put into the normal gray speech bubble. In the old version, it was a separate card with a white background which was attached inside the actual speech bubble. This appears to be set by `div.webchat-bubble-content`. I'm actually not as concerned about this change since I prefer single cards the way they are now, and as that class is common to all cards there doesn't appear to be a way to format carousels differently.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not understanding. Are you saying you don't like the way my styles affect standalone cards or are you saying you don't like the way my styles affect carousels? Web Chat v4 does use different classes for those so there's no reason you have to apply the same styles for both. And since you say the screenshots are already in the question, are you saying that my styles aren't affecting your attachments at all?

Comment: The attachment/carousel styles don't seem to be affecting anything. Is there a way I can DM you a link to one of the samples and you can take a look at the CSS? There is stuff coming from all over the place (styleOptions, AdaptiveCardsHostConfig, my stylesheet, and some weird .css classes though they may come from the first two) and I'm not sure I can adequately share in this question. As I mentioned I don't see any attachment or webchat_carousel classes, they all seem to be part of webchat-bubble-content.

Comment: Yes of course you can email me. Let me know what browser/version you're using too.