# Bot Framework 3.0 - Adding dynamic values an interdependent values to drop down

Tags: node.js, botframework

We have an Azure based Chatbot built on NodeJS. We have an adaptive card that looks like this:

As you can see we are asking the Group and Role information in the form of a text box. With text boxes, there is every chance for a manual typo.

[image]

So we are trying to explore two options:

1. Can we populate the contents of a drop down manually, say from a query to a database etc?.
2. Can we populate the contents of a drop down ( say Role ) based on what was selected for the drop down ( say Group )?.
   Note: Group has multiple Roles. And the number of Roles in a Group vary. So we want to increase usability by dynamic population of content.

Please share any references/thoughts that you may have. We are using Microsoft Bot Framework V3.

Thanks,
Pavan.

Comment: Is this Web Chat or what?

Comment: We have both web chat and direct line configured Kyle.

Comment: This is a client problem and not a bot problem, so you need to share information about your client. Is this some kind of React Native app?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: Yes Kyle we are still working on it. And ours is not a REACT app. MS Teams and webchat are our modes of communication. I am not able to see any triggers that can be applied on one drop down so that the second drop down can listed to it and change.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61257462/drop-down-on-adaptive-card-bot-framework

Comment: I think they are the same. We too are trying to see if based on what the user had filled in drop down1, the second drop down could be set to show the values that are applicable to the selection in the drop down. We use MS Team, WebChat and Directline and prefer same behavior across them. Looks like this is not possible. BTW can you please point me to some documentation ( say, as an answer to this question ) so that it serves as reference for others.

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For client-side questions like these, it's irrelevant whether you're using the Bot Builder SDK v3 or v4.

When you're using Web Chat there are some tricks you can do with Adaptive Card extensibility. But when you're using Teams you don't have control over the client and so you can only use the Adaptive Card functionality that Teams has defined for you.

Have a look at this blog post to learn more: https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/